# What does the acronym PDA stand for in the aviation domain

Tags: parachute, hang-glider

While reading [an article](http://www.kite-enterprises.com/articles/quantum.htm) about Hang Gliding reserve parachutes, I came across the acronym "PDA".  The article seemed to imply that this is a type of parachute and [a further google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pda%20parachute&client=firefox-b-1&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwink9rVq_TcAhWNd98KHVLtCZkQ_AUICSgA&biw=1547&bih=813&dpr=1) seems to confirm that.

What I haven't been able to find is a source explaining what this acronym stands for.  [Wikipedia disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDA_(disambiguation)) offers no help and neither do several aviation glossaries I a familiar with.  Lastly, [a search for "PDA" in this forum](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=PDA) provides no results.

Comment: In the article they mention a "Pulled Down Apex", which is a particular type of parachute.  Perhaps that's what they meant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pull-down apex. It's an additional attachment point in the center of the parachute. Putting force on it makes the parachute open up more like a half-donut, rather than a half-sphere. That provides more effective area for an annular parachute. That hole in the middle is needed for stability.

[image: Example]

Link: [one product of this type](https://www.independence.aero/en/products/rescue-parachutes/smart.html) with a bit of explanation.